# Projectile curve using GDI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I've calculated the range of projection with given angle, height and velocity. How can you draw a projection curve of that using GDI?

Comment: Perhaps it could be modeled as one or more bezier splines? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162811(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd make points, then draw lines between these points. You could smooth it after to get a curve.